# Creating a Loop to Conditionally Create a Button

Tags: vba, loops, excel, button

I'm working with a 5 column variable range. The first column simply contains ascending numbers from 1 to the end of the list. The fifth column contains profits that are either positive or negative.

I'm trying to create a loop that will go through the 'profit' column and determine whether each cell value is positive. If it is positive, I want it to create a button that is placed over the corresponding cell in the 'number' column. I want it to do this for every row with a positive 'profit' value.

When the button is clicked, I want it to create a new sheet called "Investment (corresponding number from 'number' column) Overview" [i.e. "Investment 2 Overview"]. Then I want it to go back to the initial worksheet and copy the value in the corresponding 'profit' cell and paste it into a table on the new sheet, and then use that table to create a chart.

I am new to VBA, but have done pretty thorough research. I found a forum post that I think is regarding what I want to do, but I can't really wrap my head around it. This website was linked as a solution to the post:
http://navpadexcel.blogspot.com/2006/11/httpwwwcpearsoncomexcelvbehtm.html

Anyway, here is what I came up with. Doesn't work, but hopefully gives an idea of what I'm trying to do:

```
For Each c In ActiveSheet.Range("Profits").Cells
     If c.Value > 0 Then

Dim t As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set t = Range(c).Offset(-4, 0)

With ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(t.Left, t.Top, t.Width, t.Height).Select
Selection.OnAction
Sheets.Add.Name = "Investment" & c.Offset(-4, 0).Value & "Overview"
Worksheets("Profits").Activate
c.Select
    Selection.Copy
Worksheets("Investment" & c.Offset(-4, 0).Value & "Overview").Activate
Range("N22").Select
     ActiveCell.PasteSpecial
Range("N21").Value = "=N22 - Profits!K20"
Range("N23").Value = "=N22 + Profits!K20"
Range("M20").Value = "x"
Range("N20").Value = "y"
Range("M21").Value = "1"
Range("M22").Value = "1"
Range("M23").Value = "1"

ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.ChartType = xl3DColumnStacked
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("$M$20:$N$23")
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer, but I couldn't see anything glaringly obvious in your coding, but the last time I tried to work with creating buttons, I created a separate macro for what I wanted to do once the button was clicked, so:

```
ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add Range("A2").Left, Range("A2").Top, Range("B2").Width, Range("A3").Height
ActiveSheet.Buttons.Select
ActiveSheet.Buttons.Caption = "Hide Sheet"
Selection.OnAction = "HideMeNow"
```

Then had a separate sub named HideMeNow

What is your code doing when you run it?

-Cr1kk0

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Cr1kk0 for the answer! It pointed me in the right direction and I was able to figure it out.

Here's the code I used to cycle through my "Potential_Profits" range and for every positive value, create a button auto-fitted to the corresponding cell 4 columns to the left:

```
For Each c In ActiveSheet.Range("Potential_Profits").Cells
    If c.Value > 0 Then
     Dim t As Range
     Dim btn As Button
     c.Select
     Set t = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -4)
     Set btn = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(t.Left, t.Top, t.Width, t.Height)
        With btn
        .OnAction = "buttonMacro"
        .Caption = c.Offset(0, -4).Value
        .Name = "btn" & c.Offset(0, -4).Value
    End With
    End If
Next
```

Then I made a separate macro named "buttonMacro" (really took my creative liberty there) that was linked to the button. The macro selects the cell that the button is on top of, assigns a variable to the original cell in the "Potential_Profits" range, and creates and names a new sheet based on the row number that the button is in.

```
Sub buttonMacro()

Dim b As Object
Dim rowNumber As Range
Dim buttonCell As Range
Set b = ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller)

With b.TopLeftCell.Select
    Set rowNumber = ActiveCell
    Set buttonCell = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4)
    Sheets.Add.Name = "Sheet " & rowNumber.Value
End With
End Sub
```